# How to make a small correction in an equation in a manuscript after acceptance but before publication?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Recently one of my papers was accepted in Physical Review B.

I found that one of the equations (say, A) has some typo. This equation is not a new result, and is a standard formula in the field.

I obtained another equation (B) from the correct form of equation A (the typo in equation A occurred only while typing the manuscript), and derived new results using equation B.

If I fix the typo in Equation A, none of the other equations/texts need to be altered.

Now that the paper is just accepted, but not yet published, how do I fix the typo? I am yet to send the editors a .tex file for the manuscript.

Do we have to go through the lengthy review process once again? Or should I just let it go?

The paper was accepted for publication without any revision.

Answer (score 4):

At some point after acceptance, the journal will send you so-called "proofs" which include copyediting & typesetting changes. That is your chance to make changes. If they send you the source files you can make the changes yourself, otherwise just reply to the employee of the publisher and tell them what to change.

No peer review should be necessary.

Comment: I initially submitted a pdf to the journal, and now I need to send them a .tex file. Can I make the change right now before sending it?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Go ahead, and tell them that you've made the change.

Comment: Just make necessary changes and send it. They may not notice minor changes like this. Even if they noticed, you can always justify there was a typo and you corrected it. If they want to review it before publishing it, that should be fine. Even if they check for such minor typos, there is a high chance that your paper won't be rejected since it was accepted without revision.

Comment: Do tell them you made the change.  If the editor starts to think you're trying to sneak things past, it will only cause trouble.